# How to back a MutableList<Uri> field with a MutableList<String>

Tags: list, kotlin, inheritance, interface, uri

I have an interface that looks like that:

```
interface MyObject {
    val id: String
    val media: MutableList<Uri>
}
```

I would like to make an implementation of it where the media list is backed by a `MutableList<String>` instead of `MutableList<Uri>` (the reason I need that is explained in my long question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66506915/is-there-a-way-to-add-type-conversion-in-documentsnapshot-toobject)). The easy way is:

```
data class MyObjectPojo(
    override val id: String,
    val mediaStringList: MutableList<String>
) : Tale {
    override val media: MutableList<Uri>
        get() = mediaStringList.map { Uri.parse(it) } as MutableList<Uri>
}
```

But it's obviously inefficient (e.g. in order to get only the first element, a map operation would run for the whole list). I thought about `get() = object : MutableList<Uri> {...}`, But I realized I have to implement more then 20 members... Is there any nicer way to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to extend [`AbstractList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-abstract-list/), which could be as simple as:

```
val media = object : AbstractList<URL>() {
    override val size get() = mediaStringList.size
    override fun get(index: Int) = Uri.parse(mediaStringList[index])
}
```

That gives you a read-only view of the underlying `mediaStringList`: any changes to that are immediately reflected in the view.

Like most performance issues, it's a trade-off: it doesn't store any data itself, but needs to create a new `Uri` each time an item is retrieved.  So it's a good idea only when you need to save memory at the expense of extra processing; or when the list is likely to be big compared with the number of items retrieved.

If you want the view to be writable, you could instead extend [`AbstractMutableList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-abstract-mutable-list/), and override three more methods.  (That's left as an exercise :-)

PS. I'd suggest *initialising* `media` to this object, rather than creating it in a getter, as the latter will create a new view every time the getter is called, which is wasteful.  (If you were concerned about creating even a single view for each `MyObjectPojo`, you could wrap it in `by lazy {…}` so that it would only be created the first time it was needed — at the cost of some synchronisation.)

Comment: Nice solution! And thanks for the quick response! I will now implement it. Extensions like `List<T>.firstOrNull()` should work right (they are all built up on those 5 members at the end)? And actually I don't really need to save memory, my problem is that I need this class to use as the type for my Firestore 'set()' & `toObject()` operations. Unfortunately, it seems like they don't support the `android.net.Uri` type. If you have a better solution for that than implementing the `object : AbstractList<Uri>`, please share:)

Comment: @OmerLevy Yes, `AbstractList` implements all the other `List` methods in terms of the two that you need to override, and equivalently for `AbstractMutableList` — though in some cases it might be more efficient to override some of the other methods too.  (I don't know Android so I can't speak to its API.)

Comment: @OmerLevy BTW, thanks for the upvote and acceptance!  Though in the interests of fairness, I should probably mention that on this site it's generally good to hold off accepting an answer for a day or so, to give folks in other time-zones a chance.  (After all, someone else might come up with an _even_ better answer than mine, impossible as that may seem :-)

Comment: Hahaha, that's nice of you! Ok, I'll remove the acceptance for a day or two:)